# I'm using Mobile Navigation but does not load the dropdown menu after installing jQuery Update

Tags: navigation

After installing the module jQuery Update not shown the Menú Mobile. Why?

Comment: It seems that you have an error in javascript. You may check it in your browser console.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the correct ***Default jQuery Version*** in configuration. May be that causes this problem..